# Collapsing one hot encoded columns based on conditional in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table that contains variables that are one hot encoded. I want to collapse these variables into one column. For example, any columns that have "high", "med", or "low", I want to be one column with numerical encodings for high = 0, med = 1, and low = 2. How can I do this in `dplyr` R? I suspect pivoting will help but I'm not sure where to start. The resulting column name should contain the name of the three columns without the high,med,low designation.
For example, I would transform columns `d-high_cm1`, `d-med_cm1`, `d-low_cm1` to `d-cm1` with the numerical encodings.

input:

```
sex age    cost_cm  d-high_cm1 d-med_cm1 d-low_cm1 c-high_cm1 c-med_cm1 c-low_cm1
f   old    1        1           0         0           1           0         0
m   young  0        1           0         0           1           0         0
m   old    0        0           1         0           0           1         0
f   young  0        1           0         0           0           0         1
m   old    1        0           0         1           0           0         1
```

expected output:

```
sex age    cost_cm  d-cm1 c-cm1 
f   old    1        0     0
m   young  0        0     0
m   old    0        1     1
f   young  0        0     2
m   old    1        2     2
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer` might be the place to look. Or, if you want to do it manually, `mutate(dcm1 = 2*d-high_cm1 + d-med_cm1)` etc. would work. Backticking your column names where appropriate, obvs

Comment: How can I do a pivot_longer for only columns that contain med, low, and high and pivot those 3 matching columns based on the column names?

Answer (score 2):

We may do

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(across(contains("-"), ~ case_when(str_detect(cur_column(),
      'low') ~ . * 2, str_detect(cur_column(), 'med')  ~ . * 1,
        TRUE ~ .* 0))) %>%
   rename_with(~ str_replace(., "-(\\w+)_(\\w+)", "-\\2_\\1"), contains('-')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = contains('-'), names_to = c(".value"), 
      names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_.*")%>% 
   group_by(sex, age, cost_cm) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), max), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  sex   age   cost_cm `d-cm1` `c-cm1`
  <chr> <chr>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 f     old         1       0       0
2 f     young       0       0       2
3 m     old         0       1       1
4 m     old         1       2       2
5 m     young       0       0       0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(df1[-c(1:3)], sub("-[^_]+", "", 
    names(df1)[-(1:3)])), function(x) do.call(pmax, x *  (0:2)[col(x)]))
cbind(df1[1:3], lst1)
```

-output

```
   sex   age cost_cm c_cm1 d_cm1
1   f   old       1     0     0
2   m young       0     0     0
3   m   old       0     1     1
4   f young       0     2     0
5   m   old       1     2     2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(sex = c("f", "m", "m", "f", "m"), age = c("old", 
"young", "old", "young", "old"), cost_cm = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), `d-high_cm1` = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `d-med_cm1` = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `d-low_cm1` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `c-high_cm1` = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `c-med_cm1` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `c-low_cm1` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: Can this be done without the regex? I'm not sure I completely understanding what the regex is doing. This looks like a great solution however

Comment: @Eisen does your expected output have more rows?

Comment: No it has the same amount of rows. The columns are just  updated based on if it contains high,med,low in the column name - resulting in columns d-cm1 and c-cm1

Comment: @Eisen Your description says to change 'med' to 1, low to 3 etc.  where is the 3 case in the expected

Comment: Sorry the "3" was a typo, i meant to write 2. If you look at the resulting output (5th row) d-cm1 is labeled as 2 because it was labeled "low" in the input (because d-low_cm1 = 1) Does that make sense?

Comment: @Eisen please check the update

Comment: Why is the order of the rows different?

Comment: @Eisen  when the group by summarise was done, it changed the order

Comment: @Eisen if you want the same order use the `base R` option as in the update

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*, unite
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -c(sex, age, cost_cm),
    names_pattern = "([^.]+)-([a-z]+)_(.*)",
    names_to = c("ltr", "fctr", "key")
  ) %>%
  left_join(fctrs, by = "fctr") %>%
  mutate(value = value * fctrval) %>%
  unite("key", ltr, key) %>% 
  group_by(sex, age, cost_cm, key) %>%
  summarize(value = max(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(c(sex, age, cost_cm), names_from = "key", values_from = "value")
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   sex   age   cost_cm c_cm1 d_cm1
#   <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 f     old         1     0     0
# 2 f     young       0     2     0
# 3 m     old         0     1     1
# 4 m     old         1     2     2
# 5 m     young       0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("high"), ~ 0),
         across(contains("low"), ~ ifelse(.x == 1,2,0))) %>% 
  mutate(`d-cm1` = rowSums(.[,4:6]), `c-cm1` = rowSums(.[,7:9])) %>% 
  select(-(4:9))

#>   sex   age cost_cm d-cm1 c-cm1
#> 1   f   old       1     0     0
#> 2   m young       0     0     0
#> 3   m   old       0     1     1
#> 4   f young       0     0     2
#> 5   m   old       1     2     2
```